# sqlite delete row count

Tags: sqlite, delete-row, sql-delete

I need to write a SQLlite query that will delete rows from a table above 200.  I was thinking this would work:

```
DELETE FROM [tbl_names] WHERE count(*) > 200
```

but that gives me: misuse of aggregate function count()

I know there is a limit clause I can use, but if I use:

```
DELETE FROM [tbl_names] LIMIT 200
```

that looks like it will delete the first 200 rows.

Comment: For anyone interested, this seems to work: DELETE FROM [tbl_name] WHERE rowId IN (SELECT rowId FROM [tbl_name] ORDER BY rowId LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows in an SQLite have rowid field, which you can use to find rows greater than 200.  For example:

```
DELETE FROM [tbl_names] WHERE rowid > 200
```

You could also use an offset with your limit:

```
DELETE FROM [tbl_names] LIMIT 10000 offset 200
```

using the roqid seems to be the better choice.

Comment: My table has an autoincrement integer primary key field and, from what I've read, if you have a primary key defined it will use that for rowid, which won't work for me, since individual rows can be deleted before my query to delete rows above 200 is run.