# SQLiteException: near "ORDER" while compiling

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to delete last inserted Item from database table, but always getting SQLiteException: near "ORDER" syntax error (code 1)

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: delete from pending where url = 'server' and mobile_id = '2331' and sent = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Using following query:

```
db.execSQL("delete from pending where url = 'server' and mobile_id = '" + string + "' and sent = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: you don't need `order by ...` with delete

Comment: @PavneetSingh I have 5 records for same mobile_id with sent status equals to 0,but I would like  to delete only last inserted, otherwise its  deleting all the records

Comment: put  order in where like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028725/delete-order-by-in-sqlite-android

Comment: you can do this using nested query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested query as follows.

```
db.execSQL("delete from pending where TABLE_ID = (SELECT TABLE_ID from pending where url = 'server' and mobile_id = '" + string + "' and sent = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"));
```

TABLE_ID should be unique key id of pending table.

Comment: most clean and easiest solution

Comment: Hello  there, please have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015994/sqlite-combine-value-of-two-columns

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE ID IN
        (
        SELECT ID
        FROM
            (
                SELECT ID
                FROM table
                WHERE url = 'server' and mobile_id = '2331' and sent = '0' 
                ORDER BY id
                DESC LIMIT 1
            ) a
        )
```

Note the **a** serves as an alias for the subquery

Comment: Neither the alias nor the extra subquery are necessary.