# SQLite Combine Value of Two Columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying `get` data from database based on some logic, here is the query

```
String sql = "SELECT pr.number, pr.u_id from pro_cap pr " +
"LEFT OUTER JOIN pending p " +
"WHERE p.mobile_id = pr.u_id+pr.infant_no ";
```

Where, `value` of **mobile_id** in *pending* table is `4711`

And `value` of **u_id** is `471` and value of **number** is `1` in *pro_cap* table

I suppose to get data from database where 4711 = 4711, but unable to get...

Comment: `471 + 1 = 472`. Show the table structure.

Comment: `||` is for string concat ... but there are pitfalls like u_id = 47 and number = 11 ... would be the same as u_id = 471 and number = 1 ... why didn't you use the 2 column foreign key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For concatenating two or more columns use `||` operator.

Change your query as below :

```
String sql = "SELECT pr.number, pr.u_id from pro_cap pr " +
"LEFT OUTER JOIN pending p " +
"WHERE p.mobile_id = pr.u_id || pr.infant_no ";
```